# What are the cons of posting dmidecode output publicly?

Tags: security, privacy

I remember somewhere mentioned that posting **`dmidecode`** output publicly is risky (security/privacy).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

dmidecode contain private information:

- Serial Number
- IPMI support

but this information does not make your system vulnerable.